# resultset.getTimeStamp("column") does not return meridian indicator

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I execute the query `SELECT TIME_STAMP FROM USERS` through Oracle SQL Developer, I am getting timestamp as `11-JUL-23 02:14:40.12345678 PM`. But when I try the same query through Java JDBC, `resultSet.getTimeStamp("TIME_STAMP")` returns `11-JUL-23 02:14:40.12345678`. Here meridian indicator is missing?. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: A `Timestamp` is essentially a number. A better question might be "why is the format so similar?"

Comment: Are you using [the Oracle `timestamp` data type](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-timestamp/)? (According to that link it doesn’t have a separate AM/PM field.)

Comment: The only thing you are doing wrong is having the wrong expectations. The timestamp in the database has got no meridian indicator. As it turns out, Oracle SQL Developer formats the time stamp into the format you see, with `PM`, before displaying it to you. In Java you can format it in any way you like, including something akin to the way SQL Developer does.

Answer (score 3):

`.getTimestamp` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` object which is broken. In that sense, your question is irrelevant.

### But, to answer it...

Timestamp is literally that - specifically, a 'time stamp without timezone'. It doesn't contain the meridian. Or the hours. Or the minutes. Or the year. It is a 'number of milliseconds since jan 1st 1970 UTC' + a second number for the nanoseconds, that is all. You can't extract anything 'human reckoning' from that at all (day, year, month, hour, meridian, none of that). Instead you can use that + a time zone of your choosing to say: Okay, **in this timezone** (which the timestamp object **does not** contain, so it's coming from elsewhere!), at the time this timestamp represents, what time is it? In human reckoning (hours, minutes, days) terms?

So, two things are silently happening here:

- Some code is shoving some arbitrary timezone in there. Presumably, the system default zone. This is bad. Your code should make this explicit.
- Some code is taking this notion and deciding how to print it. It's this printing code and not the object itself, that decides whether to print meridian or not.

So, how do you fix that? You don't, go back to the root - Timestamp **itself** is broken.

### Why is it broken - what do I do instead

We have many date/time types. That's because there are different things that we all call 'time stuff'. There's moments in time, there's appointment time, and there's local time, and even various flavours of this (such as 'based on zone' vs 'based on offset').

Databases represent this too - there are many time types. [Have a look](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) - there's `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, `DATE`, and other databases have even more than that.

It is very important that you check what these types *actually represent*. For example, oracle's `TIMESTAMP` represents, straight from the docs:

> This data type contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It contains fractional seconds but does not have a time zone.

And here's the key takeaway: **That is COMPLETELY DIFFERENT from what `java.sql.Timestamp` does!!** because that has millis, which is not at all the same as year+month+day+hour+minute+second.

So, `.getTimestamp()` to read an oracle SQL `TIMESTAMP` value, whilst that sounds sane, is **completely broken**. Stop doing it.

The proper type in java that represents exactly the same thing oracle's `TIMESTAMP` does, is `java.time.LocalDateTime`. So, do that:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = resultSet.getObject("time_stamp", LocalDateTime.class);
```

Once you have an ldt, to print it, simply pick (or make) a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` instance that formats it the way you like (for example, if you want meridian, toss it in there), and call `ldt.format(theDateTimeFormatterYouMade)`.

### Why is JDBC so crappy then?

Time is hard. Most systems and programming languages didn't realize that 'human reckoning' and 'computer reckoning' cannot be unified and there are many takes on human reckoning. Hence, most systems just get it wrong. So did java, in the past, and those mistakes are now in JDBC too, and can't easily be removed because changing interfaces would break existing code. Fortunately, java did, eventually figure it out - the `java.time` package does it right. Most languages haven't caught up yet, so java actually has an advantage. For reasons not known to me, resultset and co don't have a `.getLocalDateTime(idx)` method like they have a `getTimestamp` method. However, the JDBC spec declares that dbs MUST support `.getObject(idx/colName, LocalDateTime.class)`.

More generally JDBC is incredibly hard and inconvenient to use, it wasn't meant for direct consumption. Use [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org) or [JOOQ](https://jooq.org) for a nice API.